# How do I list Docker VIP addresses?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, ipvs

I can list all container IP address inside a docker overlay network using:

```
~# docker network inspect <network_id>
```

I'm trying to do resolver troubleshooting in some Docker swarm stack. It seems that resolving is done to the wrong IP address, but I want to check if it is resolved to a VIP first. I'm talking the network between containers, not the ingress network.

In my quest I found this [Docker Issue comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30134#issuecomment-409640305). Which suggests this:

> From a debugging point of view, the tool to use are:
>
> 1. tcpdump
> 2. ipvsadm --> load balancer is done with ipvs

But I'm unable to find which `ipvsadm` options to use to print the VIP's used inside my docker network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lookup the VIP for a service with an inspect on the service itself (I typically use `jq` to format the json output):

```
docker service inspect --format '{{json .Endpoint.VirtualIPs}}' ${service_name} \
 | jq .
```

To loop over all your services, you can do a little scripting:

```
for service in $(docker service ls -q); do
  docker service inspect --format \
     '{{.Spec.Name}}: {{range .Endpoint.VirtualIPs}}{{.Addr}} {{end}}' \
     ${service}
done
```